# Custom setters and getters in Laravel

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel, laravel-4, call

Here's a tricky question.

I am building a framework in Laravel and I want my objects to interact with Rackspace in a transparent way. 
From now on I made it possible to upload/delete objects without having in mind Rackspace

```
$model->file = Input::file('thing'); // and it uploads to Rackspace.
```

The next step I want to achieve is to get the route using my config file. The behaviour would be something like `$route = $file->source` (with source with hello.jpg in the database for instance) and get $route as rackspace.com/WHATEVER/hello.jpg. The part rackspace.com/WHATEVER is in my config file, so the only thing I need is how to make this behaviour.

I have been searching extensively and I only found the `__call()` method to do so. 
The fields I want to behave like this are dynamic and are setted from an array such as:

```
public static $rackspaceable = array('source' => 'images-demo');
```

Where images-demo is a Rackspace container.

Does anyone knows to achieve that and if it is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
class Model extends Eloquent {

    public static $rackspaceable = array('source' => 'images-demo');

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if (isset(static::$rackspaceable[$key]))
        {
            return static::$rackspaceable[$key];
        }

        return parent::__get($key);
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        if (isset(static::$rackspaceable[$key]))
        {
            static::$rackspaceable[$key] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            parent::__set($key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
$model = new Model;

var_dump( $model->source );

$model->source = 'new value';

var_dump( $model->source );
```

Comment: Wow Antonio that was a great answer! It worked perfectly! Also, do you know a way to access $model->source from the __get($key) method? If I do $this->{$key} I get a `code ErrorException: Undefined property: RackFile::$source ` error.

Comment: I don't think you can, because it would cause a recursive call.

Comment: Hey there! After 4 hours of bashing my head against my screen I found a cool solution using traits.

In the trait I implement the `code __get($name)` method and I check if the getter belongs to some of the fields I want to monitor. The structure is similar to this:

`code  public function __get($name) {
    if($name == variableOfInterest) {
        return doSomethingSpecial
    }
    else return parent::__get($name)
 }`

This way I can avoid infinite recursion. Maybe it helps to someone else! :D

Thank you again Antonio!