# Laravel - Make only 3 functions for getters and setters

Tags: php, laravel, date

I believe that there are more developers who need to have a locale date format (shown in app front end) than the ones who use the default format in browsers which is 12/22/2016.

So i have made a small trait in my Laravel project for standard dates like created_at, updated_at and deleted_at:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Carbon\Carbon;

trait FormatDates
{
    protected $localFormat = 'd.m.Y H:i';


    // save the date in UTC format in DB table
    public function setCreatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['created_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
    }

    // convert the UTC format to local format
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($date)->format($this->localFormat);
    }

    // get diffForHumans for this attribute
    public function getCreatedAtHumanAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->diffForHumans();
    }

    // save the date in UTC format in DB table
    public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['updated_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
    }

    // convert the UTC format to local format
    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($date)->format($this->localFormat);
    }

    // get diffForHumans for this attribute
    public function getUpdatedAtHumanAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['updated_at'])->diffForHumans();
    }

    // save the date in UTC format in DB table
    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
    }

    // convert the UTC format to local format
    public function getPublishedAtAttribute($date)
    {    
        return Carbon::parse($date)->format($this->localFormat);
    }

    // get diffForHumans for this attribute
    public function getPublishedAtHumanAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['published_at'])->diffForHumans();
    }

    // save the date in UTC format in DB table
    public function setDeletedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['deleted_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
    }

    // convert the UTC format to local format
    public function getDeletedAtAttribute($date)
    {    
        return Carbon::parse($date)->format($this->localFormat);
    }

    // get diffForHumans for this attribute
    public function getDeletedAtHumanAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['deleted_at'])->diffForHumans();
    }

}
```

There are actually only 3 functions for those dates and those functions are:

```
set the date so it can be saved with date time picker
get the date in locale format (22.12.2016 14:39)
get the date in human readable format
```

So my question is how to make this trait to have only 3 functions instead of repeating it all the time for every single variable? Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it up similar to [Custom setters and getters in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359363/custom-setters-and-getters-in-laravel).

The `__get()` / `__set()` methods in your trait will be called prior to the `getXAttribute()` / `setXAttribute()` method in the eloquent model.

You can just fetch the dates per model with `$this->getDates()` and create a helper method to define which method you should call on which date field.

Though less code is required for this solution, personally I don't see a whole lot wrong with having specific accessors & mutators in the FormatDates trait, looking at readability.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it's not so bad if i leave it like this concerning the readability, even though it's more code

Comment: Opinions vary of course, but the above code is self explanatory and highly readable, even though it involves duplicate code. You might want to consider going for the custom __get/__set solution when the available date fields in your model vary a lot and thus making the trait more dynamic depending on the output of the model' `getDates()`. If the date fields are relatively uniform throughout your models, I, personally, don't see much wrong with the current solution.